# Unable to remove a horizontal line in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Not sure where to ask this as it's not a programming question but it's driving me nuts.
I'm using the below resume template (https://templates.office.com/en-us/modern-chronological-resume-tm16402488).  There is a horizontal line under the name/address section that cannot be selected, removed or moved.  It is not a border, footnote, etc.

How to remove it or move it?
Thanks!

[image]

[image: https://templates.office.com/en-us/modern-chronological-resume-tm16402488]

Comment: The download is a template file, so you may need to edit the template

Comment: The issue is that i've been editing the template but am unable to remove this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click the header, uncheck "Different from first page" and it should be fixed.

Comment: QuickishFM - nailed it, thank you very much.  It was driving me crazy.  I didn't see your solution on any of the MSFT posts either.  Appreciate it!

Comment: No worries! If you could accept it as solution by pressing the tick icon, it'd help me out. Thank you :)